# Is the length of HTTP GET limited to 2048?

Tags: http, url, get, uri

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp):

> the GET method adds the data to the URL; and the length of a URL is
>   limited (maximum URL length is 2048 characters)

And from the [HTTP SPEC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt):

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
>   a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
>   serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
>   provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
>   SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
>   than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> ```
>   Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>   above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>   implementations might not properly support these lengths.
> ```

Is this a mistake from w3schools?

Comment: Had a look at this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: No it's not. There is a limit if you use older version of Internet Explorer. Look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/1413133)

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: a) it wouldn't be the first time, b) RFC 2616 is very out of data, you should look at RFC 7230